# Collatz Related? $x$ is odd: If $x \bmod 3=0$ execute $x/3$, or elseIf $x \bmod 3=1$ execute $(x⋅2)+1$, or elseif $x \bmod 3=2$ execute $(x⋅4)+1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Let $x$ be an odd number:

If $x \bmod 3=0$ : execute $x/3$, or elseIf $x \bmod 3=1$ : execute $(x⋅2)+1$, or elseif $x \bmod 3=2$ : execute $(x⋅4)+1$.

I have been playing around with my calculator for hours and it keeps coming down to either $1$ or $5$
($\begin{aligned} 1\mapsto3\mapsto1\mapsto3\mapsto\ldots \end{aligned}$)
($\begin{aligned}5\mapsto21\mapsto7\mapsto15\mapsto5\mapsto21\mapsto7\mapsto15\mapsto\ldots \end{aligned}$)

Examples:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& 127\mapsto255\mapsto85\mapsto171\mapsto57\mapsto19\mapsto39\mapsto13\mapsto27\mapsto9\mapsto3\mapsto1\mapsto\ldots
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 239\mapsto957\mapsto319\mapsto639\mapsto213\mapsto71\mapsto285\mapsto95\mapsto381\mapsto127\mapsto255\mapsto85\mapsto171\mapsto57\mapsto19\mapsto39\mapsto13\mapsto27\mapsto9\mapsto3\mapsto1\mapsto\ldots
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 49\mapsto99\mapsto33\mapsto11\mapsto45\mapsto15\mapsto5\mapsto\ldots
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 919\mapsto1839\mapsto613\mapsto1227\mapsto409\mapsto819\mapsto273\mapsto91\mapsto183\mapsto61\mapsto123\mapsto41\mapsto165\mapsto55\mapsto111\mapsto37\mapsto75\mapsto25\mapsto51\mapsto17\mapsto69\mapsto23\mapsto93\mapsto31\mapsto63\mapsto21\mapsto7\mapsto15\mapsto5\mapsto\ldots
\end{aligned}
$$
I have found many questions in regards to the Collatz variants, and I am aware that proofs are currently out of the limits. Most of the questions seemed to involve even numbers being divided by $2$, where as in the above the results are only odd numbers, and so I am just curious to know:

Am I correct about the above as a conjecture, and is the difficulty in trying to solve it similar to the original Collatz conjecture (that involve even numbers being divided by 2)?

Any references are also appreciated.

Comment: For every $x$, one of the first four terms of the sequence is strictly smaller than $x$ unless $x=1,5$ or $x\equiv8\pmod{9}$. There are also arbitrarily long increasing runs by starting with $x=u\cdot 3^v-1$.

Comment: https://tio.run/##fZHNboMwEITvfoqRqkqQ/gSH9BKJvkjEweClWBhDjaOqfXlqE4nEh7DHnZlvVvb469rB5PMsqYFWHdWD1sL9JX16Ygx@tJoc1apDgXNfLqufVmlahfMbL/EJflq0MKqJxWfkKApkN8c9@F2MIxmZRJH9Hnm62kk/QPJt5AG7OPYCvkX1xI@YWFkS3V1iou3G48NGS@5izSoyxgYpzaWvyE7hbQ87FcxoBgsFZWCF@aKEv4JnGU9L9uRaui5RC4OKQFI5kmjJkseFYB@CN@711om@fUH8uYswWmVc4uWUzfM/

Comment: Every start value upto $10^8$ reaches $1$ or $5$ in at most $211$ steps.

Comment: No other cycle or diverging sequence occurs upto start value $10^9$. I continue upto $10^{10}$. I also check the even starting values.

Comment: Equivalently every number hits a number of one of the forms $7\cdot 3^n$ ,$5\cdot 3^n$, or $3^n$

Comment: Reached $4\cdot 10^9$. Still for every start value, we land in $1$ or $5$.

Comment: @Peter Thank you! To me it seemed like the runs are shorter than the original Collatz conjecture. Does it seem like that with these huge numbers too?

Comment: Finished the range upto $10^{10}$. The conjecture is still "alive". Every start value upto $10^{10}$ (also the even values) lands in $1$ or $5$.

Comment: The smallest counterexample must have one of the forms $81k+44,81k+53,81k+80$. Using this, I could show that every start value upto $10^{11}$ lands in either $1$ or $5$.

Answer (score -2):

this sequence T is equivalent at:

\begin{array}{lllll}
\text{0) }&x/3&\text{with}& x=3n :&T(x)=n&\text{with probability}\quad1/3\\
\text{1) }&(2x+1)/3&\text{with}&x=3n+1 :&T(x)=2n+1&\text{with probability}\quad1/3\\
\text{2) }&(4x+1)/3&\text{with}&x=3n+2 :&T(x)=4n+3&\text{with probability}\quad1/3\\
\end{array}

The growth is:

$T(x)/x=( (1/3) (2/3) (4/3) )^{1/3}=2/3<1$ so it decreases.

and cycles occur when:

$x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{k-1} x_1 = T(x_1) T(x_2) \ldots T(x_{k-1}) T(x_k)$

Hence:

$3^k > 2^{k1+2 k2}\qquad(1)$

$k_i$ is the number of values $i\bmod(3)$ in cycle: $k=k_0+k_1+k_2$ and if $k_0=k_1=k_2=k/3$, equation (1) is ok, thus equibrobability is possible, e.g.:

$x=T(x):$

\begin{array}{llll}
\text{0) }&x=x/3 :&x=0\\
\text{1) }&x=(2x+1)/3 :&x=1:&\text{cycle of lenght 1 (fixe point)}\\
\text{2) }&x=(4x+1)/3 :&x=-1:&\text{no solution in }\mathbb{Z}+\\
\end{array}

$x=T(T(x)):$

\begin{array}{lll}
\text{00) }x=(x/3)/3 :&x=0&\\
\text{01) }x=(2x/3+1)/3 :&x=3/7:&\text{no solution in }\mathbb{Z}+\\
\text{02) }x=(4x/3+1)/3 :&x=3/5:&\text{no solution in }\mathbb{Z}+\\
\text{10) }x=((2x+1)/3)/3 :&x=1/7:&\text{no solution in }\mathbb{Z}+\\
\text{11) }x=(2(2x+1)/3+1)/3 :&x=1:&\text{previous solution}\\
\text{12) }x=(4(2x+1)/3+1)/3 :&x=7:&\text{cycle of lenght }2\quad\{7;5\}\\
\text{20) }x=((4x+1)/3)/3 :&x=1/5:&\text{no solution in }\mathbb{Z}+\\
\text{21) }x=(2(4x+1)/3+1)/3 :&x=5:&\text{cycle of lenght }2\quad\{5;7\}\\
\text{22) }x=(4(4x+1)/3+1)/3 :&x=-1:&\text{no solution in }\mathbb{Z}+\\
\end{array}

and go on to maybe find other cycle of lenght $>2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).