# Collatz Related? Are there any generalized rules for the following?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

Following up on my last question, [Last Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4234036/collatz-related-x-is-odd-if-x-bmod-3-0-execute-x-3-or-elseif-x-bmod).

I have also noticed the following:

If $x \bmod 5=0$ : execute $x/5$, or elseIf $x$ ends in $1$ : execute $(x⋅2)+3$, or elseif $x$ ends in $3$ : execute $(x⋅4)+3$ , or elseif $x$ ends in $7$ : execute $(x⋅6)+3$, or elseif $x$ ends in $9$ : execute $(x⋅8)+3$.

This time they all end in either $1$ or $3$ or $27$.

In comparison, I have also tried the following:
If $x \bmod 5=0$ : execute $x/5$, or elseIf $x$ ends in $1$ : execute $(x⋅4)+1$, or elseif $x$ ends in $3$ : execute $(x⋅8)+1$ , or elseif $x$ ends in $7$ : execute $(x⋅12)+1$, or elseif $x$ ends in $9$ : execute $(x⋅16)+1$.

In this case I had runs that seem to go infinite.

My question this time is:

Are there any generalized rules as far as when these conjectures work and when they don't ?

Comment: Nope.  And thrashing around testing arbitrary functions, chosen haphazardly, is not likely to advance understanding.

Comment: @David G. Stork I am sure that it will not advance in proving, but why not for understanding? Some thing is going on here besides the original conjecture.

Comment: Because there are infinitely many such functions... you need a reason why YOURS is worthy of time and effort.

Comment: @David G. Stork. I apologize if my questions seem arrogant. My intention was never to claim that anything is mine at all. I am well aware that I am not renewing anything not known to any professional mathematician. But as an amateur that likes learning for the fun, and after searching up that there are no duplicates, it’s really a great way for me to learn.

Comment: @IsaacBrenig You should know that there is a generalized version of the Collatz conjecture that was proven to be undecidable. To improve the question (and also to justify your choice to get an interesting rule) , you should point out the start values that seem to lead to a divergent sequence. That makes users curious and will improve the score of this question.

Comment: Particular cases might be solvable however. It would be interesting , if you had found such cases. Maybe someone can solve some particular case you mentioned.