# What exactly is a Collatz-like Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, dynamical-systems, collatz-conjecture

What exactly is a Collatz-like problem? Let $f:\mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{N}$. The Collatz function states that the following iterated map will eventually equal to 1:

$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if}\  2\mid n\\
3n+1, & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$
I have seen many different iterated functions ([1](https://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_073.htm), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236933/collatz-related-are-there-any-generalized-rules-for-the-following), [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353434/borderline-collatz-like-problems) )being described as Collatz-like or Collatz related once the search is for bounded or unbounded orbits. Searching for bounded or unbounded orbits is the intention of the person behind the function and doesn’t constitute a definition to me (but I could be wrong). This led me to wonder if there is a formal mathematical definition for a Collatz-like problem.

Comment: I think it makes sense to consider every case of the generalized version of the Collatz-conjecture to be a Collatz-like problem. Note that this generalized version was proven to be undecidable (wikipedia even mentions a small subset still proven to be undecidable). This might already indicate why such problems are so difficult in general.

Comment: There probably isn’t a definition. Usually, people use “-like” to indicate an informal similarity, and use a term like “generalized” or “general” when there is a formal definition.

Comment: Right. Consider this: do we have a mathematical definition for two proofs (or theorems, or conjectures ...) to be "similar"?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.00908

Answer (score 1):

Any function of the form $3x+n$ where $n>1$ fills the bill nicely. For example:

$3x+5$ when $x=27$

[image]

The section of this sequence that’s producing the loop is:  $49,152,76,38,19,62,31,98,49$

Comment: Just to remind other readers: using $3x+n$ is equivalent to allowing rational values for $x$ and evaluating $ y/n = (3x/n+1)$ and "automatically" there pop up cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Would $f( n / 3 \iff n \mod 3 = 0$ or $n *2 \pm 1 |  n \mod 3 = 0$) be “Collatz Like”

If $n$ is divisible by three then $n=n/3$ and if $n$ is not divisible by three then $n=2n$ plus or minus one such that $(2n \pm 1)$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: no that way you always go to small numbers

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't think there is one "universally accepted standard definition", the if (x mod y = z) switch definition [from your possibility number 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236933/collatz-related-are-there-any-generalized-rules-for-the-following) has one monumental result that brings mindshare to it: as mentioned at https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309224.pdf , "John H. Conway (1972), Unpredicatable Iterations" proves that there is an undecidable problem with that form, which then begs the question: is there a solution to any Collatz-like problem with that form, including Collatz itself? Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/5a9t0b/can_we_solve_any_collatzlike_problem/

That definition is also mentioned at [Small Turing machines and generalized busy beaver competition by Pascal Michel (2004)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397504003718) which states it as:

$$n ≡ r \mod d \implies g(n) = \frac{a_r(n − r)}{d} + b_r$$

and provides the following other names:

> Such functions are named one-state linear operators algorithms (OLOA) by Kascak
> [6] and periodically linear functions by Wirsching [26].

That paper, which is mentioned at: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11611/what-is-the-nearest-problem-to-the-collatz-conjecture-that-has-been-successful/11614#11614 explains that there is a 5-state Turing machine whose halting problem (for arbitrary integer inputs) is equivalent to determining if a Collatz-like problem with that form always goes down to 1, possibly suggesting that that halting problem for 5 state machines is already very hard.

Answer (score 0):

I would write down some properties of Collatz sequences, and then call anything that has the same properties a “Collatz-like” sequence.

There is a small constant $c_0 = 1$. Collatz sequences are defined by having a starting value $x_0 >= c_0$, and $x_{n+1}$ is calculated from $x_n$ using a simple rule. We have observed that for all numbers examined so far, the sequence ends in a short cycle of small numbers, in this case 1 - 2 - 4 - 1 and so on, and it seems a reasonable conjecture that this is indeed the case for every starting value $x_0$, with no proof in sight.

Equivalent to the conjecture that every $x_0$ ends in the same cycle is the conjecture that for every $x_0 >= c_1 = 2$, the sequence will encounter an $x_n < x_0$. This makes checking a single $x_0$ much faster, and there are patterns that we can take advantage of, but checking say all $2 <= x_0 < 2^{64}$ is still an enormous amount of work.

If your sequences have these properties I will call them “Collatz-like”.